# crystal report return 'Fail' if value is 'Fail' in more than 2 rows

Tags: variables, crystal-reports, count, report

I have a student result

```
 Subject    Total Obtained Result    
    English     75   45       Pass
    Maths       75   28       Fail
    Science     75   25       Fail
```

I want in crystal report that if a student is fail in 2 or more than 2 subjects then return a varaible or formula field with value 'Fail' else 'Pass'

hope u guys will understand my problem.

I tried this in formula field but it didnt worked.

```
numbervar x := 0;
stringvar text := '';
if {tblExamDetail.Result} = 'Fail' then 
x := x + 1;
if x >= 2 then
text = 'Fail';
else
text = 'Pass';
```

but it gives me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a formula to the `details` section:

```
// {@test}
if {tblExamDetail.Result} = 'Fail' then 
  1
else
  0
```

Add this formula to the student group's `footer` section:

```
// {@passfail}
if Sum({@test},{tblExamDetail.student}) > 2 then 
  'Fail'
else
  'Pass'
```